# Rewrite rules not loading css/font/img for ibm http webserver

Tags: apache, http, url-rewriting, webserver, url-rewrite-module

I am using ibm http webserver and I can't get the css/fonts/img loaded for a customized page with rewrite condition

All my files for customized page are under /opt/ibm/htdocs/abc/xyz folder which got a folder structure like this:

- xyz.html
- img
- css
- css/font

Rewrite condition loads xyz.html fine but without css/fonts/img

THis is what i got under httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/abc/trigger.on -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /abc/xyz/xyz.html [PT]
```

If trigger.on is not available it goes to our regular website and I also can access the xyz.html with css/fonts/img loaded fine main using
https://mywebsite.com/abc/xyz/xyz.html

What am I missing?